# Label x axis on an histogram without overlapping the label using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am plotting an histogram, and I would like to label the x axis. But when I label it the numbers overlap. How can I fix it?

```
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

degree_sequence = sorted([d for n, d in G.degree()], reverse=True)  # degree sequence
# print "Degree sequence", degree_sequence
degreeCount = collections.Counter(degree_sequence)
deg, cnt = zip(*degreeCount.items())

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.bar(deg, cnt, width=0.80, color='b')

plt.title("Degree Histogram")
plt.ylabel("Count")
plt.xlabel("Degree")
ax.set_xticks([d + 0.4 for d in deg])
ax.set_xticklabels(deg)

# draw graph in inset
plt.axes([0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5])
Gcc = G.subgraph(sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)[0])
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
plt.axis('off')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=20)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.4)

plt.savefig('degree_distribution.png')
plt.show()
```

[image].jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the tick labels as `deg`, which is an iterable with all degrees existent in the network. If you don't set the labels, since `x` in the  barplot is the degree sequence, matplotlib will reduce the tick-labels frequency so that it looks good. So basically just skip those two lines where the ticks and labels are set:

```
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(100,0.05,seed=1)
degree_sequence = sorted([d for n, d in G.degree()], reverse=True)  # degree sequence
# print "Degree sequence", degree_sequence
degreeCount = collections.Counter(degree_sequence)
deg, cnt = zip(*degreeCount.items())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
plt.bar(deg, cnt, width=0.80, color='b')

plt.title("Degree Histogram")
plt.ylabel("Count")
plt.xlabel("Degree")

# draw graph in inset
plt.axes([0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5])
Gcc = G.subgraph(sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)[0])
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
plt.axis('off')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=20)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.4)

plt.savefig('degree_distribution.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This actually works, but I don't have the exact value for the bins, yet I can live with that

Comment: You should @RodolfoMoreschi By default the tick labels are set to whatever `x` is in the plot, which is `deg`: `plt.bar(deg, cnt,...`

Answer (score 0):

You can space out your `xticks` by using the step parameter in the `range()` function:

```
ax.set_xticks(range(0, max(deg), 5))
```

Comment: This is not working. It shows strange labels, starts from 73 instead of 0, it shows then 63 and at the end of the ax 69